# Password Validation (8 letters, 2 numbers, no symbols)

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Component;


import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class DoSomething {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
"Please enter a password: "); 


    boolean number = false; 
    boolean character = false; 
    boolean symbol = false; 
    boolean length = false; 
    Component frame = null; 
    int counter = 0; 

char [] letters = password.toCharArray(); 
for (char c: letters){


if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
    if (password.matches("a-zA-Z")) {
        counter++;
        character= true;
    }
}

if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
    counter++;
    symbol = false;
}

if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
    counter++; 
    if (counter >=2) {
        number = true;
    }
 if (password.length()>=8) {
    length = true;
        }


if (character && length && number && !symbol){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Your Password " +password +" is valid")
 }
}
}
```

Edited -- it still hates length (even if it is 8 or more)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use regular expressions ?

```
public static boolean isValid(String password) {
    return password.matches("([a-zA-Z]{8,})([0-9]{2,})");
}
```

This expression (if I'm not mistaken) checks if there are 8 or more characters(lowercase and uppercase) **and** if there are more than two numbers in the password. Symbols such as $, @, [space] will trigger the expression as false. **EDIT:** This regular expression only allows a password with 8 (or more) grouped characters and 2 (or more) numbers. Numbers cannot be separated (1MyPassword3) as this will flag the password as invalid. Further investigation will be required.

See the java API for regular expressions:

[java 7 Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

[java 8 Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Also check out [String.matches(String regex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)

**Reaction on comment**

This code should suit you better then:

```
int letterCount = 0;
int numberCount = 0;

/*
 * Loop through the password and count all the letters and characters
 */
for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
    char c = password.charAt(i);

    if (Character.toString(c).matches("[a-zA-Z]")) {
        letterCount++;
    }

    if (Character.toString(c).matches("[0-9]")) {
        numberCount++;
    }
}


if (letterCount > 8) {
    // password has 8 or more characters
}

if (numberCount > 2) {
    // password has more than 2 numbers
}
```

Then if you really want to check length as well, you can add this piece of code (outside the for-loop)

```
if (password.length() >= 10) {
    /* Since we need 2 numbers and 8 characters, the password
     * can never be valid if it's smaller than 10 characters
     */
else {
    /*
     * Invalid password
     */
}
```

Comment: Right, but I have to have separate error messages for each part (if less than 8 letters, or less than 2 numbers... etc.)
I am also super new to coding and we are *supposed* to be using the "isDigit", "isLetter" type of methods but now its having issues with my number one and length one... I havent even attempted with symbols

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your conditions for a valid password were:

- At least 8 letters
- At least 2 numbers
- No symbols
- At least 10 characters long

```
String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a password: "); 

boolean number = false; 
boolean character = false; 
boolean symbol = false; 
boolean length = false;  
int letterCounter = 0; 
int numCounter = 0;

Component frame = null; 

char [] letters = password.toCharArray(); 

for (char c: letters){
    if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
        letterCounter++;
    }
    else if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
        numCounter++;
    }
    else {
        symbol = true;
    }
}

//Checking booleans
if (password.length()>=10) {
    length = true;
}
if (letterCounter>=8) {
    character = true;
}
if (numCounter>=2) {
    number = true;
}

if (character && length && number && !symbol){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your Password " + password + " is valid");
    System.out.println("Success");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: OMG IT WORKS!!! THANK YOU! 

Is it always the case that booleans should be separate from their counters? 

Seriously -- thank you!

Comment: You could put the if statements to check the booleans inside the loop, but it would make your program less efficient since you don't know if there are enough letters and numbers until after checking every character. You were also only using one counter for both letter and number, which would only be useful for checking length. You should have separate counters since you are checking for the number of letters and numbers separately. Additionally, you could get rid of the `if (password.length()>=10)` entirely because if there are at least 8 letters and 2 numbers, there will be at least 10 chars.